# Is binary more ideal than decimal?

Tags: binary, number-systems

We only chose the decimal system because we have 10 fingers. Binary is the most basic positional numbering system, so would it make sense to say that it would be the most ideal system? Is it better than hexadecimal, base-12 base-10 and base-8 since those seem arbitrary? Would it be considered the most "wholesome" positional system?

Comment: What do you mean by "basic positional"? Also, the Babylonians counted in base $60$ -- one can argue that this is the best, as it is possible (and easy) to count up to $60$ on your fingers.

Comment: What base would you choose if you had $s$ different symbols to form numbers?

Comment: But 60 is just some arbitrary number related to human physiology. I'm wondering since 2 is the simplest way to base numbers, if that would mean it's the most ideal. Maybe in a 1000 years, do you think people would consider base-2 the truest number system? Not necessarily in an applied sense but in a pure sense.

Comment: Binary system is the most cost efficient that's why they built the computers using binary system (Binary gates)

Comment: zoli- base-s of course, but should s just be some random number of symbols?

Comment: Also, does changing bases affect the "quantity" of prime numbers? We know 7 is a prime in base-10. Is its binary representation also a prime?

Comment: How many symbols can we display with our ten fingers. (Hint: none, one, two, ..., ten.) So, given 10 fingers what system would be ideal, if not ideal but natural?

Comment: The Celts used base $20$… You're confusing a number and its representation in a given basis. What about  systems without a basis. Is XVII not prime?

Comment: I would agree that 10 is natural since we have 10 fingers to count with, but in a vacuum, wouldn't you agree that base-2 is the most basic form of numerical representation? From there you could argue that since it's the most basic, it is also the best way to represent numbers.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hxOXZ.png                                                                                Because we have 11 symbols to use: None, one, two,... ten.

Comment: The ideal number system is of course base $\omega$. Where every natural number is a single digit.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: but only infinipedes can calculate on their fingers (or toes) to base $\omega$, $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: @Rob: How do you explain ancient cultures using base 60, then? Also Chuck Norris can count up to $\omega$ and back without problems.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: good point: I was forgetting the possibility of a creature with a finite number of fingers and infinitely many knuckles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematically, possibly the most "pure" numbering system is the system consisting of zero and the successor function $S$. In this system, instead of writing the first several non-negative integers as $0, 1,2,3,4,5,6$ and so forth, we write

$$ 0,$$ $$ S(0),$$ $$ S(S(0)),$$ $$ S(S(S(0))),$$ 
$$ S(S(S(S(0)))),$$ $$ S(S(S(S(S(0))))),$$
and so forth. It's cumbersome, but it is related very closely to the fundamental concepts of arithmetic; at least, it is much closer to the fundamentals than binary is, in my opinion.

As a practical matter, most digital electronic computers 
use binary arithmetic for most internal calculations. 
That's because "on" and "off" are relatively
simple concepts to get modern electronics to keep track of accurately.
There were attempts to use more than two possible voltage levels as
"digits" inside computers, which would have allowed computers to do their
internal calculations truly in a base higher than two, but these
efforts were not successful enough.
I think there may still be some computers (or at least electronic
hand calculators) that still use binary-coded decimal, which means
they're basically working in base ten but some of the details
(such as determining that $2 + 3 = 5$) are worked out in binary.
The only reason I can see for this is to accommodate the fact that
the humans using these computers want to see base-ten numbers going in
and base-ten numbers coming out. (The humans may also particularly
want to see "rounding" done in a base-ten fashion for some applications.)

As someone who works professionally with computers and occasionally has to
deal with binary numeric representations directly, I find that as the
numbers get larger in size it becomes very difficult to work directly
with the binary representation, simply because the numbers have
too many digits to keep track of (and certainly far more digits than
I care to have to copy). Octal and hexadecimal are much more convenient.
If we ever give up on decimal notation, I think it's much more likely
that human society will switch to octal or hexadecimal for most
numbers than that we will every make binary our usual numbering system.

Regardless of the numbering system, each number is what it is,
and most mathematical properties (other than obvious ones such
as number of digits or having the digit $6$) are not affected.
For example, a number that is prime when written in base ten
is a prime number in any system of writing the integers.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't consider having every number be the same digit. Also, thanks for clarifying the fact that the property of each number (other than symbolic notation and position) stays the same regardless of numerical system.